# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using Groupie in my app for building Nested RecyclerView with expandable cards. I notice this bug when I generated more than 60 RecyclerView items inside my nested CardView. If I add 5-10 elements to the internal RecyclerView which is inside my CardView, I'm not getting this error, but more elements always call app crash

```
A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallObjectMethod called with pending exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for RecyclerView
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int) (MessageQueue.java:-2)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.os.Message android.os.MessageQueue.next() (MessageQueue.java:323)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:135)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:5417)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:726)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:616)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this bug you need to disable your delayedTransition. Just remove this call of beginDelayedTransition

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(viewHolder.itemView.calendar_items_recycler, AutoTransition())
```